# Full Outer Join on 3 conditions or alternative

Tags: sql-server

I am in a situation where I need to Full Outer Join two table based on three conditions but I am not sure how to,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TableA.*
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.IDB = TableB.IDB
INNER JOIN TableD ON TableD.ID = dbo.TableC.IDA
FULL OUTER JOIN TableA
```

Now what I want from TableA is using these conditions,

```
ColumnA = TableD.Column1
ColumnB = 'someGivenParameter'
Condition = All of 3 columns ColumnA, ColumnB or ColumnC of TableA are Null
```

**Table**

```
ColumnABC   Key Value   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
1   TestFlag1   TRUE    1         14    NULL    NULL
2   TestFlag2   FALSE   2          1    NULL    NULL
3   TestFlag4   FALSE   NULL      NULL  uid-1828    NULL
4   TestFlag3   FALSE   NULL      NULL  NULL    NULL
```

**Desired Output**

```
ColumnABC   Key Value   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
1   TestFlag1   TRUE    1         14    NULL    NULL
3   TestFlag4   FALSE   NULL      NULL  uid-1828    NULL
4   TestFlag3   FALSE   NULL      NULL  NULL    NULL
```

When ColumnA = 1 and Column C = uid-1828

### EDIT

What I actually want in simple words is,

### I want to apply Inner Join for a single column with multiple values, but I am not able to find a proper solution :(. Thank You

```
Inner Join TableA where ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA or ColumnA = NULL
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put the 3 condition in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how, do I need to add a join to other table first then where statements ?

Comment: Can I use Outer Apply ? which one is best practice